# Could not open the editor: Assertion failed:

Tags: apache-flex

when i open .mxml flex file in eclipse it gives error

Could not open the editor: Assertion failed:

Does any one know about it

Comment: Check the workspace log at  `${workspace_dir}/.metadata/.log`.  You should find a more detailed error message and a stack trace.

Comment: Are you using Flex Builder 3 with Eclipse 3.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its better to stop searching when you are in Flash and Linux. Here in this link its very much transparent. I tried all the fix provided out there, nothing did really worked what new comers are looking for.

Details: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flex/flexbuilder_linux/releasenotes.html#sysreq

Note: GUI will never work, which we are thinking and Autocomplete etc will also not work. So Flash and Linux is actually useless and time lose. The best thing is keep reporting Adobe for this. Because they are counting our Linux Vote.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can give which operating System and version, IDE version, Flex plugin version, detail of error message. You can try ;

1. Check eclipse and flex plugin version compatibility if you use flex plugin. (If you use Linux operating system flex plugin compatible with eclipse 3.3 ide if not You can try to install flex plugin on eclipse 3.3 if you use 3.4 or 3.5 and so on)
2. You can download full package of flex ide instead of flex plugin on eclipse

Comment: I also used to get the same error and I usually quit Flex Builder and launch it again...and then it works fine most of the time!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your current workspace to another one, it helped in my case.
If you have disabled asking for workspace at startup you can change it here:
Window > Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same error, after moving my project to a new computer. Turns out the build paths needed to be changed in the new computer. After updating those it seemed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this a couple of hours:  my own "solution" to this was that I had Eclipse Galilieo / Weblogic 10.3.2 / Windows 7 set up correctly,  but was accidently opening an old Eclipse Helios install pointed to the same projects. In other words yes, its likely a slight path difference or a new name for an updated resource along one of your paths. "assertion failed" is such a generic exception that you could get with so many different softwares, that I thought this input wouldnt hurt...